# Rename files in subfolders by adding "_ParentFolderName"

Tags: automator

I have hundreds of **Parent Folders**, each containing a few **subfolders**. Each subfolder has a few **.docx** files and a few **.pdf** files.

I need to rename all my files inside the subfolder by adding **"_" + ParentFolderName**.

**Before:**

```
ParentFolder
├── Folder1
│   ├── Filename1.docx
│   ├── Filename1.pdf
│   ├── Filename2.docx
│   └── Filename2.pdf
└── Folder2
    ├── Filename1.docx
    ├── Filename1.pdf
    ├── Filename2.docx
    └── Filename2.pdf
```

**After:**

```
ParentFolder
├── Folder1
│   ├── Filename1_ParentFolder.docx
│   ├── Filename1_ParentFolder.pdf
│   ├── Filename2_ParentFolder.docx
│   └── Filename2_ParentFolder.pdf
└── Folder2
    ├── Filename1_ParentFolder.docx
    ├── Filename1_ParentFolder.pdf
    ├── Filename2_ParentFolder.docx
    └── Filename2_ParentFolder.pdf
```

Is there a way I can do a Quick Action on all my Parent Folders at the same time and rename all my files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* with a **Run Shell Script** *action* using the *settings* as shown in the image further below, and by replacing the default *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the following **shell script** *code*:

***Example* **shell script** *code*:**

```bash
for d in "$@"; do
    [ -d "${d}" ] || continue
    while IFS= read -r l; do
        mv "${l}" "${l%.*}_${d##*/}.${l##*.}"
    done < <(find "${d}" -type f \! -name '.*')
done
```

**Notes:**

To use the **Automator** *Quick Action/Service*, in **Finder** select the **ParentFolder(s)** containing the *subfolders* and the *files* within them you want renamed with the *name* of the **ParentFolder** added to them, and then *right-click* and select e.g. **Add ParentFolderName to Files** from the **Quick Actions** or **Services** *context menu*.

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown above, was tested as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* under **macOS Catalina** and with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

If the *settings* in the **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* are set as shown in the image below, then technically `[ -d "${d}" ] || continue` is not really needed, however it also doesn't hurt to have it in the *code* as it just ensures what being passed is a *directory*. Just consider it as *error handling*.

Pay attention to the *settings* shown in the image below of the **Automator** *Quick Action/Service*.

[image]

Comment: it worked like a charm. That was amazing. In the near future, I will need to add the ParentFolderName before the File Name. As in "ParentFolder_File", instead of the above "File_ParentFolder" which you just did. [Sorry for asking] But could you also write this Shell Script?

Comment: Should I create another topic for this other Shell Script? @user3439894

Comment: @Daniel4321, RE: "In the near future, I will need to add the ParentFolderName before the File Name. " --  To have the **Automator** _Quick Action/Service_ rename the target _files_ with the **ParentFolder** _name_ added to the beginning of the _filename_, just modify the _target operand_ of the `mv` _command_ to accommodate and the rest of the _code_ remains the same. The _shell script_ is using **Parameter Expansion** to build out the target _filename_. Have a look at **Shell Parameter Expansion** in the **Bash Reference Manual** or **Parameter Expansion** in the **The Z Shell Manual**.

Comment: for d in "$@"; do
    [ -d "${d}" ] || continue
    while IFS= read -r l; do
        mv "${d}" "${d%.*}_${l##*/}.${d##*.}"
    done < <(find "${d}" -type f \! -name '.*')
done        Should it be like this @user3439894 ? I think I got this one wrong

Comment: @Daniel4321, In my _example_ **shell script** _code_, just change `mv "${l}" "${l%.*}_${d##*/}.${l##*.}"` to: `mv "${l}" "${l%/*}/${d##*/}_${l##*/}"`

Comment: Thanks @user3439894! Just marked it! About the other Shell Script, should I start a new discussion? (I'm not from a tech background and I'm not sure I can code it by myself)

Comment: @Daniel4321, In my _example_ **shell script** _code_, just change `mv "${l}" "${l%.*}_${d##*/}.${l##*.}"` to: `mv "${l}" "${l%/*}/${d##*/}_${l##*/}"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user3439894. Nothing happens by making this change. Maybe there is something that also needs to be changed on the rest of the script?

Comment: @Daniel4321, The only thing that needs to change in the _example_ **shell script** _code_ presented in my answer to have the **ParentFolder** _name_ added to the beginning of the _filename_ is to change the `mv` _command_ to `mv "${l}" "${l%/*}/${d##*/}_${l##*/}"` and it will be e.g.:`./ParentFolder/Folder1/ParentFolder_Filename1.docx` -- Please note that I test everything before I post it as that's how I know is works.